# How to properly discretize and solve the Liouville equation?

Tags: probability-distributions, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, dynamical-systems

Consider some dynamical system $\dot{\textbf{X}}=F(\textbf{X})$ where $\textbf{X}$ is discretized along a 1-dimensional spatial coordinate $\textbf{x}=(x_1,\dots,x_N)^T$. Let $\rho(\textbf{X},t)$ be the probability density function, then the Liouville equation describes the evolution of $\rho(\textbf{X},t)$ given by,

‎$\begin{align}‎
‎\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}=‎-\sum_{j=0}^{N}\frac{\partial}{\partial X_j}‎‎(F(\textbf{X})\rho(\textbf{X},t))
\end{align}‎$

Here is where I may be confusing myself. If we want to solve this numerically then we need to discretize the phase space. I will assume that $X_j \in \mathbb{R}^L$ for each $j$. This means that $\rho$ is a lattice in an ultra-high dimensional phase space of size $L^N$. The Liouville equation is therefore out of reach to solve numerical for even modestly sized spatial grids.

My question is, am I thinking about this correctly? I spoke to someone who said that I am double discretizing, which is a mistake. However, this is the way that I see the problem so I am looking for either a verification of this method or for someone to point out how I am making an error.

Comment: Once you’ve discretized the spatial dimensions you’re left with a system of ODEs for $\rho$. See if the method of lines works for you.

Comment: I do apply the method of lines once I discretize both the spatial dimension(s) and the phase space ($X_j$). Each spatial point $x_j$ therefore has a system of $L$ ODEs for each discrete value of $X_j$. Since there are $N$ spatial points, this represents a system of $L^N$ ODEs in total. Is that correct?

Comment: To improve your question, consider clarifying briefly the relationship between $\mathbf{X}$ and $\mathbf{x}$ and $t$.

Comment: $\textbf{X}$ is the state vector such that $\textbf{X}=(X(x_1,t),...,X(x_N,t))^T$ where $\textbf{x}=(x_1,...,x_N)^T$ is the discretized spatial coordinate, and $t$ is time. Please let me know if I should clarify this further.